# Parse and produce binaries with Leex and Yecc

Tags: erlang, leex, yecc

Most of my code is using binary representation for utf8 strings. Unfortunately the scanner and parser, that I generated with Leex and Yecc respectively, don't seem to accept binaries. Is there any option or anything to do for Yecc and Leex generated code to 1) accept binaries as input and 2) produce binaries?